# Possible problem with linked lists and limits of the Lookupfield in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, jquery, custom-list, spservices

I have set up a Parent/Child linked list, each parent item can have multiple different child items linked to it.
To connect child items to the parent I use a lookup field on a field on the parent list.

Ok, so my possible problem is this:

Ive read that SharePoint 2010 had a limit to 20 lookup items, however SharePoint 2013 has a threshold of 96 as far as I can see from this [Software boundaries and limits for SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx#Column).

The thing is that over time the parent list will have several hundred items, and each parent item will have several linked child items.

I understand that that exceeding this threshold could have consequences on serverload, so is there any workaround for this? 
What I got so far is if I use something like 
[SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) i could populate a textfield with all ids from the parent list, and by that linking items, although only visually for the user.

Has anyone come over a similar problem? Any possible solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read that limitation differently - in that you can only have up to 96 different columns in your list which are defined as Lookup columns.  From the way you have described your list it sounds as if you are only using one Lookup column and it is a single value column - so this is actually one of the possible 96.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, it seems sometimes one needs a fresh set of eyes

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate a bit more? I'm having the same issue where I'm dealing with over 20 kids (names) that are not view-able due to this limitation in SP 2013.